# Windows authentication configuration questions

Tags: bonobo

I installed version 6.3.0 of the bonobo server on a windows 2008 r2 box. I followed the instructions and all it was well with the out-of-the-box settings.

Now, I wanted to enable Windows Authentication. The goal is that the developers don't have to enter a password when they access the remote repository.

I started with this [article](https://bonobogitserver.com/windows-authentication/). Firstly, I am not sure about the sequence of making the changes. Should it be done before running it the first time? Or after? It's not clear. Anyway, I did it both ways, and in both cases it doesn't work.

Scenario 1: Left everything out-of-the-box, I added myself as a user. After I made the web.config change I was still presented with the login page, and when I typed the password, I was redirected back to the login page.

Scenario 2: I shut down IIS, I made all the changes, and before restarting IIS, I updated the web.config as per the windows authentication article. I also disabled Anonymous Access and enabled Windows Authentication. After I restarted IIS, when I tried to access it, I got:

1. The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long. I fixed this by adding: `maxQueryString="32768"` to the `requestLimits` tag.
2. Now I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when I try to access the root page.

The documentation is not clear on how you have to configure this thing for windows authentication. It looks to me that you need to leave the out-of-the-box settings, define your users, make sure one of them is admin, then change the setting to windows authentication. As soon as you turn on the windows authentication the admin user can't be used. I assume the server is trying to find the current user in its own database.

One other thing, if you turn on windows authentication in the web.config, do you need to enable the Windows Authentication in the IIS Authentication for the app and turn anonymous access off? I would think so, but the documentation doesn't specify anything. What happens if I am logged in with an account on different domain than the box with the bonobo server?

Is there someone that can clarify what has to be done exactly to get the windows authentication running?

Thanks

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS - this seems to be an error (endless loop of redirections) in Bonobo that is not fixed so far (6.3.0.632).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you could solve the problem meanwhile

if not, change the "AuthenticationProvider" to "Windows" and "MembershipService" to "ActiveDirectory".
Check your Web.config if the following is uncommented

```
<appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="AuthenticationProvider" value="Windows" />
    <add key="MembershipService" value="ActiveDirectory" />
    ...
    <add key="ActiveDirectoryDefaultDomain" value="<your.domain>" /> 
    <add key="ActiveDirectoryBackendPath" value="~\App_Data\ADBackend" /> 
    <add key="ActiveDirectoryMemberGroupName" value="Developer" /> 
    <add key="ActiveDirectoryTeamMapping" value="Developers=Developer" /> 
    <add key="ActiveDirectoryRoleMapping" value="Administrator=Developer" />
    ...
</appSettings>
...
<system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: I got it working a while ago but not hooked up to AD. It uses its own user repository which is fine.

Comment: then try the changes
I was almost despaired but that worked for me

Comment: @MichaelM., what protocol do you use: http or https? And what authentication methods are enabled (and what are disabled) for your site in IIS?